# Laravel - too many redirects issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I'm on a project, the website have two types of users **Admin** and **User**. I made an **middleware** for the **admin**, the **middleware** is working correctly but when I try to login an issue showed up:

> too many redirects

my **routes**:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@getIndex',
    'as' => 'welcome'
]);
Route::get('/{form?}', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@getIndex',
    'as' => 'index'
]);
Route::post('/exsist',[
    'uses' => 'UserController@postLogin',
    'as' => 'login'
]);
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'],function(){
    Route::group(['prefix' => '/admin','middleware' => 'admin'],function(){
        Route::group(['prefix' => '/my'],function(){
            Route::get('/home', [
                'uses' => 'AdminController@getHome',
                'as' => 'admin.home'
            ]);
        });
    });
    Route::group(['prefix' => '/'],function(){
        Route::get('/home', [
            'uses' => 'UserController@getHome',
            'as' => 'home'
        ]);
    });
});
```

and my **controller**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
class UserController extends Controller
{
        //main page
    public function getIndex($form = ''){
            if(Auth::check()){
                if(Auth::user()->isAdmin()){
                    return redirect()->route('admin.home');
                }else{
                    return redirect()->route('home');
                }
            }
            return view('welcome', ['form' => $form]);
        }
        //main login (index page)
        public function postLogin(Request $request){
            //validation
            $this->validate($request,[
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'pass' => 'required'
            ]);
            //authintecating user 
            if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request['email'], 'password'=>$request['pass']])){
                if(Auth::user()->isAdmin()){
                    return redirect()->route('admin.home')->with(['success'=>'You have successfuly loged in as Admin!']);
                }else{
                    return redirect()->route('home')->with(['success'=>'You have successfuly loged in as User!']);
                }
            }
            return redirect()->route('index')->with(['fail'=>'Wrong Email or Password!']);
        }
        public function getHome(){
            return view('home');
        }
}
```

why does the browser gives me an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
Route::get('/{form?}', [
'uses' => 'UserController@getIndex',
'as' => 'index'
]);
```

To:

```
Route::get('/form/{form?}', [
'uses' => 'UserController@getIndex',
'as' => 'index'
]);
```

I believe when you go to the '/' route, the '/{form?}' route is being executed.

Comment: man, you're a genius (y).. I't embarrassing how I did think of that